# Проверка функций на булево значение

Tags: python

Подскажите правильно ли я понял данные строки кода:

```
def checkbuy(investment):
    if not pos_dict['in_position']:
        if df.Buy.values:
           return True
        else:
           print('already in a position')
```

Данная функция первым действием проверяет словарь на отсутствие строки in_position, если ее нет, выполняется проверка фрэйма данных(ячейки в таблице) на наличие там True и если оно там есть, функция возвращает True. Если есть хотя бы словарь, он печатает уже на позиции. То есть по сути эта запись, эквивалентна вот этой, более понятной по смыслу для новичка.

```
def checkbuy(investment):
    if not pos_dict['in_position'] = True:
       if df.Buy.values = True:
          return True
       else:
          print('already in a position')
```

Если я не прав, объясните подробно, кому не лень.

Comment: Во-первых, тут попытка присваивания, а не сравнение, такой код вообще синтаксически некорректен: `if not pos_dict['in_position'] = True:`. Во-вторых - нет, не следует сравнивать булевый результат с True или False, нужно просто как есть его использовать как условие в if.

Comment: В-третьих, `df.Buy.values` скорее всего не булевое значение, а набор каких-то значений (условно - список), сравнение с True даст False, при этом непустой список будет считаться "истинным" значением.

Comment: Столбец Buy содержит значения либо True либо False. Ссылку на код оставил ниже. Вот сам код который формирует фрэйм данных df['Buy'] = (df.Close > df.SMA_200) & (df.stochrsi_k < 0.05)

Comment: Это сути не меняет. Даже если это гарантировано булевое значение, сравнивать его с True, чтобы в итоге опять получить булевое значение, совершенно бессмысленно, и считается плохим стилем кода. Вот ссылка на соответствующий кусок pep8: https://pep8.org/#:~:text=Don%E2%80%99t%20compare%20boolean%20values%20to%20True%20or%20False%20using%20%3D%3D%3A

Comment: Мне для понимания хочется усвоить, какое условие прописано в данном коде. Явной проверки на True там нет, но строка проверяет именно на True, а если False срабатывает исключение. Выражусь точнее. По смыслу это то что я написал во втором примере?

Comment: Коротко, для понимания - два приведенных вами фрагмента кода не эквивалентны.

Comment: Тогда я совсем запутался. Если по смыслу значение должно быть равно True, в этом и есть суть проверки.

Comment: if проверяет не на True, а на истинность. Истинность значения можно проверить через функцию bool, поэтому эквивалентным будет код в примере в ответе ниже. Про истинность почитайте например эту статью: https://tproger.ru/translations/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/

Comment: Тогда почему False не срабатывает? Оно тоже булево.

Comment: Очевидно потому что `bool(False)` дает `False`, значит если в условии if стоит False, то сработает ветка else. Вы статью сначала прочитайте.

Comment: Вот тут видимо и пробел. Буду изучать ваши статьи. Спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: Еще никто не написал. Ваша фраза `Данная функция первым действием проверяет словарь на отсутствие строки in_position, если ее нет, выполняется проверка ` неверна. Если в словаре нет такого ключа, то вылетит ошибка `KeyError`. Тут считается, что данный ключ есть и он приводится к `True`, как описано в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это будет эквивалентно коду:

```py
def checkbuy(investment):
    if not bool(pos_dict['in_position']):
        if bool(df.Buy.values):
           return True
        else:
           print('already in a position')
```

А далее нужно знать, что при приведении значений к типу `bool` действуют такие правила:

| Тип | Значение | bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `bool` | `True` `False` | без изменения |
| `int`,`float` | `0` не `0` | `False` `True` |
| `str` | пустая строка `""` любая другая | `False` `True` |
| коллекция | пустая не пустая | `False` `True` |
| `NoneType` | `None` | `False` |

Судя по названию, в поле `df.Buy.values` лежит какая-то коллекция и тут, соответственно, проверяется, что она не пустая и не `None`.

Comment: Еще стоит None в табличку добавить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Исходя из слов автора и логики, строчка if df.Buy.values: как раз проверяет значение на True, так как там может быть всего два варианта, либо True, либо False. Вот ссылка на полный код и ролик автора - https://youtu.be/VZQg4KSmpQU